# Ribbon greyed out, add documents missing, app pool recycle fixes, what's root cause?

Tags: bug

I have a really strange SP 2010 issue I'd like to get to the bottom of.  Occasionally, I will get a call in the morning that "Add document" link is missing, and the ribbon buttons are greyed out on a library.  Typically this occurs for all libraries in all sites in a given web application.  Recycling the app pool for the one web application fixes the issue, and it generally remains fixed for several days.  I can't correlate with any particular ULS error or other event.

What could be causing this behavior, and what is the best fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out, if this is a farm issue, of specific front end server is the "bad guy". Then try to inspect ULS log on this specific server.

Maybe users could open the IE console to see if there are any JS errors.

Isn't this the time when some kind of job is running? Timer job, SQL backup, anything that can slow down the server response time.